# Scala deserializing JSON with json4s issue

Tags: scala, json4s

when I am deserializing a JSON with the following simple code usign json4s

```
package main.scala

import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

  object Main {

    case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val jsValue = parse("""{"name":"john", "age": 28}""")
      implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
      val p = jsValue.extract[Person]
    }
  }
```

Is giving the following error.

> Exception in thread "main" org.json4s.package$MappingException:
>   scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;
>   Case classes defined in function bodies are not supported.

Does anyone know why it happens?

Comment: It seems that the answer is in the error. You should define your case class outside your `Main` object.

Comment: Unfortunately it happens also when I do it in an external object like:
object Main {
    case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
}

Comment: You don't need to define it in an object. A case class can be defined as top level in a package.

Comment: I tried out your code and it worked for me.  I used version 3.3.0, maybe you've got an old version of jackson, or different scala version - try change the lib version

Comment: Thank you it was a library issue - not really sure what, but upgraded Scala SDK to the latest version and worked fine :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75947449/run-a-scala-code-jar-appear-nosuchmethoderrorscala-predef-refarrayops

Answer (score 2):

As it came out in the comments, this limitation has been surpassed with newer version. However you could have made this work by moving the `case class` definition outside your `main`:

```
package main.scala

import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

// here!
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val jsValue = parse("""{"name":"john", "age": 28}""")
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    val p = jsValue.extract[Person]
  }

}
```

Comment: The problem seemed to be purely related to json4s - scala - jdk versions, I tried by myself to do this change as well but with no success. Anyway usually what you suggested seems to be the right solution :)

Comment: Ok, sorry, I noticed that in a comment you wrote it was still inside the `Main` object. Good to know anyway.